# Make image visible on div:hover but not if another image in that div is hovered?

Tags: css, hover, css-selectors

On my [photography portfolio](http://element17.com), I have thumbnails set up so that when you hover over the thumbnail (which are actually divs with background-image set to the thumbnail), a magnifying glass icon (which is an absolute-positioned img) is set via CSS to opacity:1.0.

However, for some images I'll have wallpapers available for download (the first image in the top-left is an example).  To indicate this, I'll have a monitor icon (also absolute-positioned) inside this div as well (in the opposite corner).  When this image is hovered over, I don't want the magnifying glass icon to appear.

EDIT:

Here is the actual HTML as generated by PHP:

```
<div class="thumbnail" style="width:240px; height:160px;">
  <a href="gallery/01_CONSTRUCTS/Steam.jpg" class="shadowbox[CONSTRUCTS]" title="Steam">
    <span class="rounded_corners thumb_back" style=" background-image:url('gallery/01_CONSTRUCTS/thumbs/Steam_thumb.jpg');">&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="rounded_corners hover_dim">&nbsp;</span>
    <img class="zoom" src="images/zoom.png" alt="Zoom" />
  </a>
  <img class="thumb_new" src="images/new.png" alt="New" />
  <a class="wall_hover" href="gallery/01_CONSTRUCTS/wallpaper/Steam.jpg">
    <img class="wallpaper" src="images/monitor.png" alt="DownloadWallpaper" />
  </a>
</div>
```

And the relevant CSS:

```
.thumbnail {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.thumbnail:hover, .thumbnail:hover .zoom {
  opacity: 1.0;
  -webkit-opacity: 1.0;
  -moz-opacity: 1.0;
}

.thumbnail a.wall_hover + a .zoom {
  display: none;
}

.thumb_new {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.zoom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3px;
  right: 3px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in;
}

.hover_dim {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  transition: background-color .25s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .25s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: background-color .25s ease-in;
}

.thumbnail:hover .hover_dim {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.wallpaper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 3px;
}

.rounded_corners {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Comment: You need to edit your question to accurately reflect the structure of your page so you don't get answers that apparently don't work without knowing why.

Comment: @BoltClock Sorry, have done this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if your structure is now correct. It is similar to Jane's answer, only it needs to be `.wall_hover:hover` not `.wallpaper:hover`.

```
.thumbnail:hover > .wall_hover:hover + .zoom {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
}
```

### Update Do to Your Break

You really need to learn some about what css selectors are actually doing, else you could break things again. So, let me help that education along. First, your "new" (current as of now) html structure is this:

```
<div class="thumbnail" style="width:240px; height:160px;">
  <a class="shadowbox[CONSTRUCTS]" title="Steam" href="gallery/01_CONSTRUCTS/Steam.jpg">
    <span class="rounded_corners thumb_back" style=" background-image:url('gallery/01_CONSTRUCTS/thumbs/Steam_thumb.jpg');">&nbsp;</span>
   <span class="rounded_corners hover_dim">&nbsp;</span>
   <img class="thumb_new" alt="New Image" src="images/new.png">
   <img class="zoom" alt="Zoom In" src="images/zoom.png">
  </a>
  <a class="wall_hover" href="gallery/01_CONSTRUCTS/wallpaper/Steam.jpg">
    <img class="wallpaper" alt="Download Wallpaper" src="images/monitor.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

***That will not work to achieve the effect you want*** (through pure css, anyway). You have to "swap" positions on the `a` tags. Short example (some code removed for brevity):

```
  <a class="wall_hover">
    <img class="wallpaper" >
  </a>
  <a class="shadowbox[CONSTRUCTS]">
   <img class="zoom" />
  </a>
```

The reason for this is that css can make selections *within* elements or in certain cases of *following* elements, but ***not*** preceding elements or *parent* elements. So that is why the html order must change, because you want to affect `.zoom` with `.wall_hover`. We are doing that using the adjacent sibling selector `+` which selects only the element *immediately following*. So now, to get your css to work, you need:

```
.thumbnail:hover > .wall_hover:hover + .shadowbox[CONSTRUCTS] .zoom {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
}
```

Note the change is because you wrapped `.zoom` in a parent element `shadowbox[CONSTRUCTS]`. What the above is saying is:

> When **.thumbnail** is being hovered, then go to its immediate child (**>**)
>   that is a class of **.wall_hover**, and if it is being hovered, then move
>   to its immediately adjacent sibling and if that is a
>   **.shadowbox[CONSTRUCTS]** class, then select its child element of
>   **.zoom**. You could add a **>** before **.zoom**, but it is not necessary in
>   your case (actually, it is really not necessary before **.wall_hover** in
>   your case either, but I kept it for illustration purposes.

Comment: Crap, broke it fixing some semantic issues that were causing a problem in IE.  Do you think you could have another look?  Thanks!

Comment: Scott, thank you very much.  This is my first time rolling a design completely from scratch, so for the most part I've never had to think that hard about this.  Thanks for educating me. :)

Comment: It did in fact, with a slight modification; the selector is now `.thumbnail:hover > .wall_hover:hover + a[class*='shadowbox'] .zoom` because the shadowbox[] class is different for each album.  This works like a charm though, and I have a much better understanding now of how these selectors are put together, so if I should change the semantics again, I should be able to cope.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

**Place .zoom after .wallpaper in your html**

```
<div class="thumbnail" style="background-image:url('img.jpg'); position:relative">
  <img src="monitor.jpg" class="wallpaper" />
  <img src="magnifying.jpg" class="zoom" />
</div>
```

**so css will**

```
.thumbnail:hover > .wallpaper:hover + .zoom {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: @NaOH this doesn't work because the HTML you have placed in your question is not the HTML that you have in your site. This would work if it was actually the HTML you were using.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS with the sibling selector, but only if you switch the order of the images:

```
.thumbnail .wallpaper + .zoom {
    display: none;
}
```

As I can see in your website you have a more complex structure. The images are contained inside `a` tags. You will need to apply the sibling selector to the `a` tag like this:

```
.thumbnail a.wall_hover + a .zoom {
    display: none;
}
```

Note that for this to work you will need to put `a.wall_hover` as the first link in the `div`.

There is another alternative using jQuery, just put this line on document load:

```
$(".thumbnail").has(".wallpaper").find(".zoom").hide();
```